# Phonegap Local and Remote Build Difference

Tags: cordova

Why the local and remote build of phonegap are different in terms of the resulting application?

I've worked with the **www** directory and building remotely with no problem; today, I started doing it locally but the resulting applications has many differences like: no splash screen and different permissions.

Why is this? how do you build locally and have the same result Phonegap has.

Answer (score 2):

Local building does not make use of the config.xml the same way that remote building does. The main difference is that local builds do not place the icon or splashscreen images for you.

For android place the images in:
/platforms/android/res/drawable

named icon.png and splash.png

For iOS:
/platforms/ios/PROJECT_NAME/Resources/icons

/platforms/ios/PRJECT_NAME/Resources/splash

Answer (score 1):

While having the same problem with Phonegap local/remote builds, i found the following blog post, with explains some of the differences. It has helped me to understand how to do some (redundant) stuff to have the same results from local/remote builds:

- http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/